How can I fix this RLS policy issue with Supabase on .insert()?
I am in the process of creating a habit tracking app and am using Supabase PostgreSQL. I am implementing RLS in the habit table but cannot for all that is good figure out this issue. On the click of the 'create habit' button, it sends the info to the Supabase API, but returns with a 403 Error ."new row violates row-level security policy for table \"habit\". I have been on this problem for 3 days and am about to go crazy.
Here is my code:
export default function AddHabit({token}) {

    const [color, setColor] = useState('rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)');
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [formData, updateFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        streak: 0,
        color_hex: color,
        dates_completed: [""],
        times_per_day: "",
        days_goal: "",
        user_id: token.user.id
    })
    
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        updateFormData((prevFormData) => {
            return {
                ...prevFormData,
                [event.target.name]:event.target.value
            }
        })
    
        //console.log(formData);
    }

    //console.log(token.user.id);

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            
            const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('habit')
            .insert([
                    {
                        name: formData.name,
                        streak: formData.streak,
                        color_hex: formData.color_hex,
                        dates_completed: formData.dates_completed,
                        times_per_day: formData.times_per_day,
                        days_goal: formData.days_goal,
                        user_id: formData.user_id
                    }
            ]).select('*')
            console.log(formData);
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error found: ", error);
            };
            console.log(data);
            navigate("/home");


        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    } 

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <h1 className="text-4xl py-8 text-white font-bold">Add a Habit here!</h1>

            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 divide-x-2 divide-zinc-500">
                <div className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4 pr-16">
                    <h2>Create</h2>
                    <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
                        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Habit Name?" required className="input input-bordered input-white "/>
                        <input type="number" max={24} name="times_per_day" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Times per day?" required className="input input-bordered input-white"/>
                        <input type="number" max={1000} name="days_goal" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Goal (How many days)?" required className="input input-bordered input-white"/>
                    </div>

                    <ColorPicker id="color" value={color} onChange={setColor} hidePresets={true} hideControls={true} hideOpacity={true} hideInputs={false} />              
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4 p-4">
                    <h2>Preview</h2>
                    <HabitTile  name={formData.name} hex={color} times_per_day={formData.times_per_day} days_goal={formData.days_goal}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleSubmit} >Add this Habit</button>
        </div>
    )
}

RLS policy definition:

Supabase Full Screenshot

Please add the definitions of your RLS policies. It might be that you added a restrictive policy without adding at least one permissive, or the condition you used always evaluates to false.

@Zegarek I updated the post with a screenshot of my RLS policy(current). Sorry it is a screenshot from my phone as I am away from my computer.

Is that the only RLS policy on that table? Did the user_id values you got from console.log(token.user.id) and console.log(formData); fully match?

@Zegarek Yes, and that’s why I’m stuck. Even if I change the RLS policy to matching user_ids, it still doesn’t work even if the user.id = authenticated user id

Is it a permissive or a restrictive policy? Try to add one permissive policy with a condition that just says true. When multiple policies of the same command type apply to the same command, then there must be at least one PERMISSIVE policy granting access to the relation, and all of the RESTRICTIVE policies must pass. Thus all the PERMISSIVE policy expressions are combined using OR, all the RESTRICTIVE policy expressions are combined using AND, and the results are combined using AND. If there are no PERMISSIVE policies, then access is denied.

It is permissive. What should I change? Added the full screenshot to the end of the question.

You should be passing through an object not an array of objects to the .insert method. Also make sure that you have a select policy in place since you are calling .select('*') after you insert the data.
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('habit')
  .insert({
    name: formData.name,
    streak: formData.streak,
    color_hex: formData.color_hex,
    dates_completed: formData.dates_completed,
    times_per_day: formData.times_per_day,
    days_goal: formData.days_goal,
    user_id: formData.user_id
  }).select('*')

